# divide two different sized dataframes by all options

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframes question.
I have two dataframes:
They both have one column and a lot of rows.

I want to divide the first df rows by the first row of the second df, then divide the first df rows by the second row of the second df, and the third and forth till the end...

For example:

df1 is:

```
A
4
8
3
5
```

df2 is:

```
A
2
3
```

The output should be:

```
A
2
4
1.5
2.5
1.33
2.667
1.667
```

**Important**: I want to do it without for loops.

thanks

Comment: Either I don't understand what your desired output is, or you didn't finish it. I assume it's the latter? 
Second, why no for loops? Is this just arbitrary, or is there something you are trying to accomplish with this restriction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [np.divide.outer](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html):

```
import numpy as np

res = np.divide.outer(df1['A'].values, df2['A'].values).reshape(-1, order='F')
out = pd.DataFrame(data=res, columns=['A'])
print(out)
```

**Output**

```
          A
0  2.000000
1  4.000000
2  1.500000
3  2.500000
4  1.333333
5  2.666667
6  1.000000
7  1.666667
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = [4,8,3,5]
>>> b = [2,3]
>>> a_list = [y/x for x,y in itertools.product(b,a)]
>>> a_list
[2.0, 4.0, 1.5, 2.5, 1.3333333333333333, 2.6666666666666665, 1.0, 1.6666666666666667]
```

Once you get two lists from the two dataframes, using a cross product, you can get the combination of the two lists. Then just a simple division for the final answer.

Comment: just like the `pd.concat([d1['A']/i for i in d2['A']]).to_frame()` answer I deleted, this would be incredibly slow on a large dataframe. I think a `numpy` solution would be best, since the OP does not want to loop since having a large dataframe.